# Updating a single column is creating sqlite syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm trying to update a single integer value in a column of a table to 1 from 0.  When creating the database, I set all values of the column to zero using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < setups.length; i++) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_SETUP, setups[i]);
        values.put(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_PUNCHLINE, punchlines[i]);
        values.put(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_USED, 0);

        db.insert(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
```

Then, in the actual activity, I'm doing:

```
private void findNewJoke() {
    JokeDb jokeDb = JokeDb.getInstance(this);
    SQLiteDatabase theDb = jokeDb.getDB();
    String selection = JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_USED + "=" + 0;

    // Query database for a joke that has not been used, update the fields
    // theJoke and thePunchline appropriately
    String[] columns = {JokeDbContract.TblJoke._ID,
                        JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_PUNCHLINE,
                        JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_SETUP,
                        JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_USED};

    Cursor c = theDb.query(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.TABLE_NAME, columns, selection,
                        null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst() == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_retrieving_joke, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name),"No jokes retreived from DB in JokeActivity.findNewJoke()!");
    }
    else {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        theSetup = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_SETUP));
        thePunchline = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_PUNCHLINE));

        String updateSelection = JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_SETUP + "=" + theSetup;

        values.put(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_USED, 1);

        theDb.update(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.TABLE_NAME, values, updateSelection, null);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the update:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: .... while compiling: UPDATE jokes SET used=? 
WHERE setup=Why do programmers always mix up Halloween and Christmas?
```

It seems as though I'm not getting an actual value set for the used column.  What the program ultimately does is cycle through jokes where used=0, then sets used to 1 when it has been viewed.  So the query only pulls those jokes that aren't used yet.  I have a feeling I'm missing something simple, one can hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are having problems with quotation marks.

Example:

```
String updateSelection = JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_SETUP + "=\"" + theSetup + "\"";
```

However, the recommended way to do this, would be:

```
theDb.update(JokeDbContract.TblJoke.TABLE_NAME, values, JokeDbContract.TblJoke.COLUMN_NAME_SETUP + " = ?", new String[] { theSetup });
```

It is better to use field = ?, because this helps sqlite cache queries (I believe).

Comment: That was it.  Here I was thinking I had set my values up incorrectly b/c of the syntax error it was giving with the SET clause.  Thanks for your help.